# Does .NET have a way to sort a list between bounds?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting

Simple question so I don't have to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Does .NET have a method equivalent to

```
// sorts a list in-place between bounds [a, b)
public static void SortBounds<T>(this List<T> list, int a, int b)
{
    // ... 
}
```

(possibly with an optional predicate)?

Example:

```
var list = {1, 5, 3, 1, 9, 2, 4 }
list.SortBounds(0, 4);
// now list is {1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4 }
```

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. What happened to the `9`? Otherwise, I would suggest [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ce6t5ad(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @MatthewWatson the upper bound is exclusive (`[a, b)`) and doesn't include the `9`.

Comment: @Amy If that were true, it wouldn't include the `5` either - but there it is, in the output...

Comment: @MatthewWatson the range is `[0,4)`, which is `1, 5, 3, 1`, which is sorted in place.

Comment: @Amy right.. which means the `9` should be before the `2`, as it is outside the range that is being sorted, so it should be unchanged.

Comment: @Amy But the output includes the `2, 4` at the end, so why doesn't it include the `9`? I'm assuming the range is the range of indices to be sorted - so fine, it would sort within that range, but the other elements would remain - the number of items in the list wouldn't change, and one element wouldn't mysteriously go missing.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see now, I misunderstood your original comment.  Please disregard.

Comment: @Amy Just to clarify, my "if that were true" comment was assuming that the range was related to element values rather than indices (which is what I thought you were getting at), hence that comment of mine doesn't actually make much sense... ;)

Comment: @Will best practice zombies is listed in your profile description twice

Comment: Different phrasing for different purposes :/

Answer (score 7):

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 5, 3, 1, 9, 2, 4 };
list.Sort(0, 4,Comparer<int>.Default);
```

Comment: The answer corresponds to @Matthew Watson comment ;) +1 for both of you.

Comment: I'm getting `1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 2, 4` when I run this - which makes sense.  It doesn't match OP's desired output, though, which I'm starting to believe is probably just a typo.

Comment: @Jonesopolis pretty sure OP typo'd

Comment: Just a note that [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ce6t5ad(v=vs.110).aspx) you can pass `null` as the comparer, and it will automatically use the default for that type. It simplifies the code slightly.